# Using Apache Tika 1.9 in Netbeans 8.0.2 and Java 8 produces HUGE executable. What to do to reduce size?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-tika

I haven't had much luck with external libraries, so I've just included the source for utilities in any project that uses utilities.

Now I have a project that requires Apache Tika, so I have to have a library setup something like this:

[image]

But to run the program from outside Netbeans, I apparently (per readme.txt in `dist` folder) need to zip the `.jar` and `lib` folder, unzip that zipped file, extract the contents, and run from wherever it's extracted to.

But the Tika lib is 45MB.

I only use 5 objects from the `tika-app-1.9.jar` library file:

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
```

How do I make a tiny subset of Tika objects into a library that will be a lot smaller than 45MB?

Or am I missing the point of what I SHOULD do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only include the `tika-core` and `tika-parsers` components, these two files should be no more than 1.2MB.

The `tika-app` jar is described on the home page as this:

> **Tika application.** Combines the above components and all the external parser libraries into a single runnable jar with a GUI and a command line interface.

So it has a lot of extra things, which your app does not need.

Comment: I got version 1,10 of both from `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-parsers/1.10/` and `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.10/` and all is well. THANK you, @meskobalazs!

Comment: Note that you'll be missing support for a bunch of file formats if you don't also include their respective dependencies

Comment: Oh. So maybe all is NOT well. So should I just put up with the 45MB .jar file?

Comment: It does not neccessarily causes problems, you should just keep in my, that some features of Tika are not included in the core and parsers jars. If you do not use these, then no problems.

Comment: I just tried to find text in a .pdf flie and it failed, so I added back the big .jar file and it worked. So since my goal is to be able to search ANY "text" file (e.g., xml, xls, bat, java, c, etc.) I'd better keep it big.

Comment: Maybe you need `tika-bundle` too. Take a look around, because I am sure that you do not 50MB of dependencies.

Comment: Right, definitely not 50MB of them. I just found `assets` in 2 .java files in my AndroidProjects folder, which is correct. And found `copy` in 15 (of 140) bat files. So I'll take that look around.

Comment: `tika-bundle` .jar  is 36MB; may as well just use the 50MB file. I found pdf parser. I'll keep looking. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachetikaparsersjar.htm)' is a good-looking source.

Comment: Is it known which file formats are supported if only the `tika-parsers` and `tika-core` jars are used?

Answer (score 2):

For long run it's better to migrate to maven or something similar. Then exclude unnecessary dependencies. E.g. if you don't need scientific formats which are parsed using NetCDF library you can exclude it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
      <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But be careful, it can lead to `NoClassDefFoundError` if you exclude something required by parsers you use.

Comment: Would be useful to run mvn dependency:tree first to get an idea of dependencies and then determine which dependency you want to exclude

Comment: I used Ivy's `<ivy:report>` (which is similar to dependency:tree), how can I know from this what can be safely excluded?