# How to get Javadoc for Apache Tika in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, apache-tika

Is it possible to install Javadoc for Apache Tika 1.9 if I have successfully added `tika-app-1.9.jar` to my Netbeans Libraries folder?

I'd like to be able to right-click or press ctrl-space with the cursor on a Tika method or class and get help.

What is the name of the Javadoc file to download in order to get started?

I have downloaded `tika-parsers-1.9-javadoc.jar` and `tika-app-1.9-javadoc.jar` and installed both to no avail.

Do I need to also download and install the source?

Here's how the Libraries look:

[image]

Here's one of a dozen attempts to get Javadoc:

[image]

Comment: The `tika-app` jar is a standalone executable jar, so in most situations you shouldn't be adding it into your own project....

Comment: [Recall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919171/using-apache-tika-1-9-in-netbeans-8-0-2-and-java-8-produces-huge-executable-wha) your advice to just use `tika-core` and `-parsers`, but then my search didn't work for `.pdf` files. You then advised also adding `tika-bundle`, but it is 36MB, so I went back to the biggie. (I don't plan on selling the app. It's just for me.) I appreciate the advice, though.

Comment: You need to add all the dependencies for those modules too. If you use Maven, it'll handle all that for you. If you don't want to use Maven but do want an easy life, you can use the OSGi bundle. If you want to do everything by hand, then you need to do it all by hand...

Comment: I don't want to do ANYthing by hand, but: "... use Maven..." (I've never done so). So here's what I tried: in Netbeans I clicked Tools | Options | Java | Maven | Dependencies  and selected to search for Download Binaries, Check Javadoc, and Check sources at `Every project open`. Not sure if that's what you mean, since I detect no change. I'd hoped this might get me Javadoc. Nope. I also chose for Maven to "Index now". It took several minutes.

Comment: I don't use netbeans, sorry. On the command line, create a basic maven pom, then add a depdendency on `org.apache.tika` / `tika-parsers` / `1.10` and Maven will fetch everything needed and make it available when you run your program. Hopefully you can find a netbeans maven tutorial that tells you how to do the same